# MongoDB aggregation Spring/Java (project with array, group and match)

Tags: java, spring, mongodb

I'm having trouble to write that query in Java using springframework.

```
db.getCollection('fish').aggregate(
        {$match : {"uploadDate" : { $gte : new ISODate("2017-05-22T00:00:00Z"), $lte : new ISODate("2017-05-25T00:00:00Z") }}},
        {$group: {_id: {lake : "$lake", type : "$type"}, count: {$sum: 1}}} ,
        {$project: {array : ["$_id.type" , "$count"], count : "$count"}},
        {$group: {_id: {lake : "$_id.lake"}, count: {$sum: 1}, types : {$addToSet : "$array"}}})
```

I was able to write match and group but I'm having trouble to add project that has array containing both id.type and count. So far I was able to write this

```
Aggregation aggregation = newAggregation(match(Criteria.where("uploadDate").gte(created).lte(newCreatedDate)),
        group("lake").count().as("values"));
```

I couldn't find any solution how to write it and I only see that you can add Fields/Strings to `project()`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'll give you the alternative as there is really no way to create the expressions the way you want.

You have to use `AggregationOperation` and use `BasicDBObject` to create the `project` stage.

Something like

```
AggregationOperation project = aggregationOperationContext -> new BasicDBObject("$project", new BasicDBObject("array", Arrays.asList("$_id.type" , "$count")).append("count", "$count"));
```

Comment: Thanks alot. With your solution I can even mix two approches

Answer (score 0):

I agree with the solution given by user2683814 but not sure solution was not working. But by using `org.bson.Document` instead of `BasicDBObject` fixed the issue, so thought to share.

```
AggregationOperation project = aggregationOperationContext -> new Document("$project", new Document("array", Arrays.asList("$_id.type" , "$count")).append("count", "$count"));
```